# Navigation from MainActivity to another fragment to login Activity back to last navigated fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, android-navigation

So here is my scenario

I have my MainActivity when I open my app which a person does not need to logged in to use.  I am trying to navigate to another fragment from the navigation menu to a fragment that requires someone to be logged in so I send them to the login activity and if logged in successfully that can finish() and be sent back to the MainActivity with the new fragment.  But unsuccessful or them pressing the back button will keep them in a loop.

I am looking for is there a best policy on how to navigate between these views and how to make sure that I can have the user be sent to the login screen if necessary while keeping the last fragment view to know which to navigate back to.

Answer (score 0):

If you go from an authentication activity back to your mainpage try adding an intent and passing some parameter to your mainactivity so that when a user is properly logged in you can present them with the required fragment.

```
Intent i = new Intent(FirstScreen.this, SecondScreen.class);   
Boolean someParam  = true;
i.putExtra(retrievalName, someParam );
```

Then retrieve it in the main activity like:

```
Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
if(bundle.getString("retrievalName")!= null)
    {
        //Set your variables so you allow user to open fragment when clicked 
    }
```

> But unsuccessful or them pressing the back button will keep them in a loop.

The back loop can be resolved by adding an override to the onBackPressed function in which you can finish the activity that is looping.

Answer (score 0):

In 2nd Activity do start 1st activty using intent

```
 Use startActivityfor result

 Intent intent=new Intent(MainActivity.this,SecondActivity.class);  
            startActivityForResult(intent, 2);// Activity is started 
   // with requestCode 2  

// In Another acitvity do this on 

          Intent intent=new Intent();  
                intent.putExtra("MESSAGE",message);  
                setResult(2,intent);  
                finish();//finishing activity
```

// if you want to handle something on Main activity override onActivityresult

```
  // Call Back method  to get the Message form other Activity  
  @Override  
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, 
    Intent data)  
   {  
             super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);  
              // check if the request code is same as what is passed  
                 here it is 2  
               if(requestCode==2)  
                     {  
                        String message=data.getStringExtra("MESSAGE");   

                     }  
 }
```

Comment: This was the correct path but your code has errors in it.  The setResult is for  RESULT_OK, RESULT_CANCELLED, etc not the 2 value.